# Efficient Way for Conversion Udp Streaming Data and Writing to rTextBox Simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, udp

I am designing a terminal program which shows the transferred data for some comm. protocols. Data comes through UDP (or TCP) to the PC form application and writing it to richTextBox. I get the UDP data in byte[] format and convert it to string to show on textbox. However conversion is too slow for streaming applications. Are there any other fast solution?

```
private void Receive(IAsyncResult ar) 
{

IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(ipadress, port);

byte[] bytes = udp.EndReceive(ar, ref ip); // Get actual data 
if (binary format) // Convert to bytes to binary for textbox
{
//This conversion is slow 
   string data = string.Join( " ",
    bytes.Reverse().Select( x => Convert.ToString( x, 2 ).PadLeft( 8, '0' ) )
   this.Invoke(new(MethodInvoker(delegate
   {
      textDisplay.Text += "\nReceived Data: " + data;
   }));
 );
else if (ascii format) // Convert to bytes to ascii 
{
   string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
   this.Invoke(new(MethodInvoker(delegate
   {
      textDisplay.Text += "\nReceived Data: " + data;
   }));
}
UdpReceive(); // Calls itself again from one upper method
}
...further formats can be added...
```

bytes to binary string conversion sounds a bit odd to me, because i have actual binary data in byte format which is 8 bit however i cant get it without conversion..

Comment: well.. what is this conditional check: `if (binary format)`?  also, what does `too slow` mean to you, because it is arbitrary unless you clarify with a problem or your expectation.  Having said all that, optimization efforts on code review is generally not well suited for this community (typically an open-ended question with no definitive answer that will be subjective and over analyzed on).  So, it's advisable that you pose this question in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) community of the Stack Exchange (SE).

Comment: if (binary format)  represents a radio button status. i have 3 radio button, 1-> BIN, 2-> DEC, 3-> HEX. If radioButtonBin.Checked = true then do that code and so on... I mean there is a data in byte array format which includes 8-bit arrays. So i already have 8 bits, and i should convert it to string to show in textbox. I think these conversions are slow.

Comment: well.. you could use `BitConverter` for sure, and you could probably just use an event instead of this MethodInvoker methodology.  but what sort of data are we talking about here, how frequent is this method called, and give us a concept and metrics for this concept of slow (how many milliseconds\seconds does it take?).  Add some [StopWatcher  diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: ran some diagnostics.. though I've used mocked data and console.out.write, that conversion is less then 0.14% of the execution time of that function, loop with 1000 iterations.  it definitely not the cause of your perceived slowness, as it took less then 29 milliseconds. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/PJqUwnw)